# How to define a property that has a type as a value

Tags: c#, winforms, properties

I want to define a property (named `FormAbout`) in a class, so that someone using this object could assign a derived type of `IFormAbout`. To do this, I have an interface and an implementation of it:

```
public interface IFormAbout : IDisposable
{
    void ShowAbout();
}

public partial class MyFormAbout : Form, IFormAbout
{
    public void ShowAbout()
    {
        base.ShowDialog();
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Here, the main `Form` with the property I'd like to define:

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    // --- This is what I don't know how to do --- //
    public Type<IFormAbout> FormAbout { get; set; }
    // ------------------------------------------- //

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        using (FormAbout frm = new FormAbout())
        {
            frm.ShowAbout();
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

The property would be set somehow like this:

```
formMain1.FormAbout = typeof(MyFormAbout);
```

Is it possible to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: although you **could** have a property of type `Type`, that´s not what you want here. You just want to assign a new instance of `MyFormAbout` to the property, don´t you? So something like `formMain1.FormAbout = new MyFormAbout()`.

Comment: ^^ Which leaves the Propertie's Type to be simply `IFormAbout`

Comment: Why not to define as `public IFormAbout FormAbout { get; set; }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found a good solution to my question, and I want to share it with you all.
It is possible to set an explicit implementation of `IFormAbout` without instantiate it, by declaring my class `FormMain` as generic:

```
public partial class FormMain<About> : Form where About : IFormAbout
{
    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        using (About frm = Activator.CreateInstance<About>())
        {
            frm.ShowAbout();
            // ...
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Then, we just have to declare an instance of `FormMain` like this:

```
FormMain<MyFormAbout> frm = new FormMain<MyFormAbout>();
```

Good enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 2):

although you **could** have a property of type `Type`, that´s not what you want here. You just want to assign a new instance of `MyFormAbout` to the property, don´t you? So the type of the property becomes `IFormAbout`:

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    public IFormAbout FormAbout { get; set; }

    private void SomeMethod()
    {           
        FormAbout.ShowAbout();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now you do not need to assign a **type**, but a **concrete instance of it**:

```
FormMain1.AboutForm = new MyAboutForm();
formMain1.SomeMethod(); // this will use the aboutForm from above
```